# Laravel book on delete remove related all posts and comments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm

this snippets is from my `Book` model:

```
 class Book extends \Eloquent
 {  

 public function delete()

     {
         // delete all related cover photos
         $this->cover()->delete();
         // delete all related comments photos
         $this->posts()->comments()->delete();
         // delete all related Blurbs
         $this->posts()->delete();

         // delete the model
         return parent::delete();
     }
 }
```

in `Post` model I wrote:

```
 function book() {

         return $this->belongsTo('Book');

     }

     function comments() {

         return $this->hasMany('Comment');

     }

     function user() {

         return $this->belongsTo('User');

     }

 public function delete()
     {

         // delete all related comments also
         $this->comments()->delete();
         // delete the model
         return parent::delete();
     }
```

in `Comment` model I wrote:

```
 function posts() {

         return $this->belongsTo('Post');
     }

     function user() {

         return $this->belongsTo('User');
     }
```

Now, when I try to remove the book it says.
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments()`

[image]

So, I understand the book models delete comments isn't working right, but don't understand how to resolve it.

Comment: Why don't specify Cascaded deletion in your database, and let the database engine do it for you.

Comment: but first, every time you need to remove a book, you need to remove all relations (same as post and comment)? It's depends on your business logic, so it's an issue about modelling your database.

Comment: @Razor- can you give me a good reference of Cascaded deletion?

Comment: mysql is well documented (jump to Referential Actions) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html, you can also check this answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior. But I can give you a Laravel answer for your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to update your database schema, with correct indices, foreign keys and, as @Razor said, cascade... refer to http://laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys